# how to hide the numeric pager in list view

Tags: asp.net

I am using a list view with page size 10 and added a numeric data pager for paging.everything is working fine but how i can hide the page number shown below when the data in list view is less than 10 and show it only data is greater than 10.
pls help me out....

Answer (score 0):

You would attach to PagePropertiesChanged event of the ListView and retrieve the number of items displayed in the current page. If the number is less than 10, set Visible to false of the DataPager.

Sorry for my english.